# Remove punctuation's in solr search

Tags: solr

I am new to the solr i have a document indexed in solr e.g

```
 {
    "foodType": "basicFood",
    "fulltext": [
      "basicFood",
      "3.718625",
      "1 tbsp",
      "Butter, salted"
    ],
    "slims": "3.718625",
    "displayText": "1 tbsp",
    "displayName": "Butter, salted"
  },
```

when i search for butter the result is null but it works fine for the query butter, how to make it working for butter also?

Comment: can you provide the query url? What are the two queries using, not clear from question?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/food/select?q=butter&wt=json&indent=true this is not working

Comment: can you also provide what is working ?

Comment: http://localhost:8983/solr/food/select?q=butter%2C&wt=json&indent=true this works

Comment: what is your FieldType for the data while indexing

Comment: text_general class="solr.TextField"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following filter to your analyzer for both index and query phase.

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^A-Za-z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
```

This is will replace all the letters from token except `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9`. To test this you might need to re-index your data, because your indexed data will have punctuations. or you can try in solr admin UI, analysis section.

**Other approach**, using a different tokenizer instead of `StandardTokenizerFactory` in the analyzer phase. You can use `LetterTokenizerFactory` which creates tokens consisting of strings of contiguous letters. Any non-letter characters will be discarded. But this can create many extra token which you might not want. **Please check before you do.**

```
Example: "I can't" ==> "I", "can", "t"
```

---

**Update**

If you need to use `WordDelimiterFilter` filter. Try the below configuration:

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilter" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="1" splitOnCaseChange="0"  generateNumberParts="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
```

This will splits words at delimiters and concatenate them again. All the other splits are `turned off` like `numeric strings`, `camel-case change` and `transitions from alpha to numeric`. If required you can `turn on` by providing `non-zero` value.

Comment: Actually the proper filter for this case is the WordDelimiterFilter that provides a lot more options and is specifically designed to handle punctuation and other delimiters. Have a look here for more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter

Comment: Yes. You can use the `WordDelimiterFilter` for removing the punctuation. But it will split the token into multiple tokens and provides the option for joining them as well. Which is essentially achieved by replacing all the non-alphanumeric characters. I would suggest, check your data set and use accordingly. Specially for the corner cases.